# Bloquear listagem de diretório no Apache

Tags: php, apache

Estou desenvolvendo um site onde possuo um painel administrativo que é acessado somente por quem possui acesso. nas páginas do painel administrativo, fiz a validação que verifica se o usuário está logado como admin para acessar a página. Por exemplo, se qualquer outro usuario tentar acessar diretamente pela URL nomedosite.com/administrativo/usuarios , ele será redirecionado à página inicial. Porém, se eu somente digitar na barra de endereços: nomedosite.com/administrativo , ele me traz uma listagem de todos os arquivos que possuo na pasta. Como proibir isso, para que ao acessar a pasta que tem os arquivos o usuario seja redirecionado, e nao somente ao acessar a página?

Comment: Via htaccess não dá pra fazer isso?

Comment: Boa dica, ainda não havia tentado. Vou tentar usar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro o fato de aparecer as pastas não é um problema de código `php`, seu servidor http (talvez seja um apache) esta com o parâmetro `Indexes` (se for um apache) habilitado o que pode ser um furo de segurança em muitos casos.

Você tem duas opções se tiver acesso as configurações do seu servidor web remova o parâmetro `Indexes` onde está o diretório do seus arquivos web

Exemplo:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Mudar para:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Outra alternativa é colocar um `.htaccess` no diretório em questão com a seguinte linha:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Sobre o redirecionamento você também tem algumas opções, você pode criar um index.html ou index.php que simplesmente redireciona todos que conectem neste seu diretório, outra alternativa é utilizar o `.htacess` novamente, veja vários exemplos [aqui](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-htaccess-file)