# Como proteger código fonte de scripts PHP sem impedir seu funcionamento?

Tags: php

Uso um provedor gratuito (Hostinger) para testar remotamente alguns `scripts` `PHP` meus. Alguns deles usam `set-cookie` para gravar `cookies` na pasta em que estão localizados. O problema é que atualmente a pasta pode ser integralmente acessada externamente, o que permite acesso ao `código fonte` dos `scripts`. Como garantir que os `scripts` funcionem (inclusive tendo permissão de gravar os `cookies`) e mantê-los protegidos do acesso à `fonte`?

Já li algumas sugestões aqui no Stackoverflow sobre edição do `.htpaccess`, mas não encontrei configuração específica para o meu caso. Proteger sem impedir acesso aos `scripts` e a gravação de `cookies`.

EDITADO::::::::::

Combinei duas possibilidades: ofuscar o script php usando uma key encript com http://dragonfly.pro3sis.com/  e adicionar .htaccess, seguindo essa orientação: [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123803/bloquear-listagem-de-diret%C3%B3rio-no-apache](http://Bloquear%20listagem%20de%20diret%C3%B3rio%20no%20Apache)

Comment: Acredito que o interpretador de códigos do PHP não irá deixar exibir o código fonte do script e sim somente o conteúdo de saída por ele gerado.

Comment: @carlos-andrade, o que ocorre é o seguinte: se disponibilizo `http://exemplo.com/script/script.php?id=1`... quando alguém digita no browser `http:/exemplo.com/script/`  tem acesso ao arquivo `php `correspondente ao script.

Comment: Sim Antonio, entendi sua colocação. Porém, mesmo se alguém digitar este endereço no browser ou até mesmo fizer o download do script, ele terá acesso a somente o conteúdo de saída interpretado pelo PHP e não o código fonte puro, ou seja, o conteúdo do arquivo exibido a ele somente será o HTML que o PHP gerou a partir do script. Salvo em casos em que o PHP não esteja rodando no Servidor.

Comment: Por ex: Se o conteúdo do script é o seguinte: `<?php echo 'Hello World!'; ?>`, o que o usuário irá ver ao digitar o endereço da página no navegador ou baixar o arquivo, será somente: "Hello Word!"